# Meteor app crashes on C9 after a while

Tags: meteor, cloud9-ide

I have a problem deploying app on c9.io,
after I launch my app (`meteor --port=$IP:$PORT`) CPU spikes for a moment, but then it turns like 3%-5% and my app is working for around 1 minute with no spikes, after that C9 IDE is reconnecting and my app crashes(with no bug whatsover, just back to console).

Any ideas?
This is really small project with mostly static content, so I don't think C9 can't hold this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was an issue on our side, we have the fix deployed just now. Please try again, the issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I'm observing this same issue from yesterday. For me it seems like issue from C9, not meteor. What a more I can run my project on my PC without any issues - try it as well. If you can confirm, then you should submit a ticket for C9 support. I did it already.

Comment: Yes, so did I, got answer that they changed something in my workspace, and problem dissappeared, so ye, it was C9 not Meteor